# Get RGB data from Camera stream

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am using `AVFoundation` framework in my app

Here is the standart code:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.preview.bounds;
[self.preview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];

[session addInput:input];

[session startRunning];
```

How to get the stream rgb data stream or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

For getting video/audio data buffer from capture session or player session,

- Create AVCaptureVideoDataOutput / AVCaptureAudioDataOutput object.
- Confirm one of your to AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.
- Add AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to your Capture/Player session.
- Implement protocol methods. You will receive the CMSampleBufferRef object containing video/audio frames as the media is being captured/played in the captureOutput... method of AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.

CMSampleBufferRef object contains media frame data, timestamp information and the format description of media. You can also specify the desired frame compression format (or uncompressed frame format) in AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.videoSettings property. I guess you will receive YUY2 or JPEG frames. So you can use CGImageRef to convert to RGB.